# How to make a readonly property to readwrite in iOS?

Tags: objective-c

I have a scenario like this,

```
@interface ClassA:UIView
@property(readonly,strong)UIView *aView;
@end
```

I have another class

```
@interface ClassB:NSObject
@property(readonly)ClassA *aObj;
@end
```

How can I access the view properties in ClassA like setHidden etc....using ClassB property

eg:

In another class ClassC.m ,

```
import ClassB.h
@implementation ClassC
//
 ClassB *bObj;
bObj.aObj.aView.hidden = YES;
```

(Note :I do not want to modify/add anything in .m for ClassA and ClassB)

I want to know if this can be achieved by writing any category methods for ClassA.

Comment: On an unrelated note - it's a bad practice to reach out across several objects to try to get some work done as in `bObj.aObj.aView.hidden = YES` because it makes your code very fragile since `bObj` knows more about `aObj` that it contains a UIView. If `aView` changes its implementation, it could break objects of class B.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to change the properties of the object, not the variable that is pointing to it. Thus the title is misleading, and you can change the object already. Nothing prevents you from calling methods on any object. If you want object immutability in Objective-C you have to code it inside the object for it to work.

Comment: My doubt is can I access the setter methods like setHidden for readonly property for aView like I have given above???

Comment: Yes, readonly prevents you from pointing the variable to a different object, but you are still able to call any method on the pointed object.